# How to Initiating a prepareForSegue function on saveAction

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, save, segue

**Technologies:** Swift, iOS8, XCode 6

I have a function like this;

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
    sender: AnyObject?)
```

where my identifier is

```
 if segue.identifier == "showDetail"
```

I want to initiate that function on saveAction. I was working with peformSegueWithIdentifier but it keeps failing. I just want to be able to call/initiate that function once I perform my saveAction. My saveAction appears in a pop-up so I'm not sure if that is causing issues.

--- UPDATE

So, I can get it to segue to the detailview after save by doing something like this

```
func saveAction() {
     if saved == true {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
    }

}
```

But, the code I have in my prepareForSegue function, doesn't seem to get hit. Does this get bypassed? I'd like the prepareForSegue function to still implement its changes.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
    sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
         do stuff here, like make the title of the ShowDetail view blue, etc..
    }
```

Comment: What is your error you get? Have you set the segue in your storyboard?

Comment: i'm trying to call it like this "self.prepareForSegue("showDetail", sender: self)", but its saying Type "UIStoryboardSegue does not conform to protocol StringLiteralConvertible"

Comment: Show us the error and your code where you try to perform the segue.

Comment: also this doesn't cause an error but doesn't seem to initiate anything either " self.prepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue(), sender: self)"

Comment: You don't call prepareForSegue yourself. The system calls it when a segue is executed. You need to call performSegueWithIdentifier. If that keeps failing, then you need to post what you've tried, and the actual error message you get, if any.

Comment: Have you made sure your Segue Identifier matches "showDetail" (see image): http://www.scott-sherwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/SetSegueIdentifier.png

Comment: Put my response in the initial post because it was getting to difficult to read in this comment.